# Return select dropdown in ajax call PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to fetch dropdown list in ajax call using PHP code.

```
$outputRes = '';
$reminderDetails["interval_type"] = value of dropdown this may varies. I want to keep value selected="selected"
```

Below is my expected output from ajax call

```
$outputRes .= '<select id="reminder_int_type" name="reminder_int_type" class="change">
                 <option value="1" '.if($reminderDetails["interval_type"] == 1){ \'selected="selected"\'; }.'>days</option>
                 <option value="2">Hours</option>
                 <option value="3">Minutes</option>
              </select>';
echo $outputRes; exit;
```

I may use code like below but i have many options tag so doesn't look feasible to me

```
$outputRes .= '<select id="reminder_int_type" name="reminder_int_type" class="change">
                 <option value="1" ';
if($reminderDetails["interval_type"] == 1){ $outputRes .= 'selected="selected"';}
$outputRes .= '>days</option>
                 <option value="2">Hours</option>
                 <option value="3">Minutes</option>
              </select>';
echo $outputRes; exit;
```

I have problem in writting right syntax .

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you can do it this way:

```
$outputRes = '';
$reminderDetails["interval_type"] = value of dropdown this may varies. I want to keep value selected="selected"

$interval = array("Days", "Hours", "Minutes");

$outputRes .= '<select id="reminder_int_type" name="reminder_int_type" class="change">';

foreach ($interval as $k => $v) {
    $k = $k + 1; // to keep your values beginning at 1.
    $outputRes .= '<option value="'.$k.'"'
    if ($reminderDetails["interval_type"] == $k) {
        $outputRes .= 'selected="selected"';
    }
    $outputRes .= '>';
    $outputRes .= $v
    $outputRes .= '</option>';
}

$outputRes .= '</select>';
```

You may want to return JSON instead and parse it on the browser side. See [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode)

Comment: This is same as code that i written. just u r looping all values. which is not required. The one i written (2nd code in my question) is better in performance. But i was looking for code (1st code in my question) . Anyways thanks for effort

Comment: So you want to add an if statement for each option?

Answer (score 0):

```
$reminderDetails["interval_type"] = 'value of dropdown this may varies. I want to keep value selected="selected"';

$result = array('array from which you want to create a dropdown');
$outputRes = '<select id="reminder_int_type" name="reminder_int_type" class="change">';
foreach($result as $optionValue=>$optionName)
{
   $is_selected = ($reminderDetails["interval_type"] == $optionValue)?'selected':'';
   $outputRes   .= "<option value=$optionValue $is_selected>$optionName</option>"

}

$outputRes . ="</select>";
echo $outputRes; exit;
```

I hope you get some idea .. I am assuming that you are creating dropdown dynamically out of a array